# What does it mean to have a function pointer type?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a class assignment that says:

> Write a declaration for a function that takes two int parameters and returns an int, and declare a vector whose elements have this function pointer type.

Since the function and vector are both int is this correct? I'm really fuzzy on pointers still. This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cin; using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::vector;

// This is my function that take two ints and returns and int
int AddFunc ( int a, int b) { int addResult; addResult = a + b; return (addResult);}

int main()
{
    vector <int> v1; // Declare a vector whose elements have this functions pointer types
    int add1, add2, add3 = 0;
        cout << "Enter two numbers to be added with my AddFunc function: ";
        cin >> add1 >> add2;
        add3 = AddFunc (add1, add2);
        cout << "The numbers added equal: " << add3 << endl;
        v1.push_back(add3);
        cout << "The first element in the vector v1 is: " << v1 [0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, helpful career advice: Don't get in the habit of writing everything on one line. It makes things hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

The function pointer type is `int (*)(int, int)`. You want this:

```
typedef int (*fptr)(int, int);

std::vector<fptr> v;
```

Example:

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int mul(int a, int b) { return a * b; }

v.push_back(&add);
v.push_back(&mul);
```

And then something like this:

```
for (f : v) { std::cout << "f(5, 7) = " << f(5, 7) << std::endl; }
```

Comment: To read that typedef line: define type `fptr` to be a pointer to function that takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you have the abilty to define a function pointer, like so:

```
int (*pfunc) (int, int);
```

This is a variable, to which you can assign the address of a function, as long as it has the specified signature, like so:

```
pfunc = AddFunc; // Assign the adress of a function
pfunc(1,2) // Now call the function through the pointer
```

Now, note that `pfunc` is the variable name, and its "official" type is `int (*) (int,int)`
Naturally, this can all get very confusing, so you'd probably wanna typedef it:

```
typedef int (*AdderFunc)(int, int);
AdderFunc pfunc = AddFunc;
pfunc(1,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment wants a vector of function pointers for your function. Function pointers are a bit difficult to read if you're not used to them. Here's a method you can use to write a function pointer type.

First, write the argument list of the function. `AddFunc()` takes two `int` arguments, so at first you have:

```
(int, int)
```

For this to be a function pointer, you prefix it with `(*)`:

```
(*)(int, int)
```

Lastly, you prefix the whole thing with the return type of the function. In this case, `int`:

```
int (*)(int, int)
```

You can use that as-is as the type of your vector:

```
std::vector<int (*)(int, int)> v;
```

This will work. However, it's usually more clear to actually define your own type for the function pointer (using `typedef`). At first, it seems tricky to do so, but it's easy. You already wrote down the type using the above method. The only thing that's missing is to give it a name. You do that by writing the name after the `*` in `(*)`.  For example `(*func_ptr)`, so you have:

```
int (*func_ptr)(int, int)
```

And that's all you need for a `typedef`:

```
typedef int (*func_ptr)(int, int);
```

Now whenever you need that particular function pointer type, instead of:

```
int (*)(int, int)
```

you can write:

```
func_ptr
```

instead. So your vector declaration becomes:

```
std::vector<func_ptr> v;
```

As far as vector is concerned, `func_ptr` is a pointer type just like any other.

Function pointers differ from "regular" pointers in that "dereferencing" them means calling the function they point to. You don't actually dereference a function pointer. Instead, you use the `()` operator on them. Doing that calls the function they point to.

Assigning to a function pointer means assigning it the address of a function. For example, if you have a variable of type `func_ptr` (which you `typedef`ed above):

```
func_ptr AddFunc_p;
```

You can assign it the address of `AddFunc()` with:

```
AddFunc_p = AddFunc;
```

Note the missing parentheses in `AddFunc`. You only write the name of the function, since you don't want to actually call that function, but rather want its address so you can assign it to `AddFunc_p`. Now you can call `AddFunc()` through `AddFunc_p` with:

```
AddFunc_p(some_int, another_int);
```

You should now be able to deduct how to put function pointers in a vector and how to apply the `()` operator on its elements. It will help to keep in mind that the vector simply contains elements of type `func_ptr`.